# How to post using axios JSON on Phoenix

Tags: axios, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to post JSON data to insert data into DB with axios.
Phoenix framework is ready for accept JSON data.

```
function register(state, action) {
    console.log(state.member) // {last_name: 'aaa', first_name: 'bbb', email: 'ccc'}
    axios.post('/members', state.member)
        .then(function (response) {
            // handle success
            console.log(response.data);
            let data = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
            // self.setState({hasError: true });
        })
        .finally(function () {
            // always executed
        });

}
```

However it cause following error.

```
Error: Request failed with status code 403(Forbidden)
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:59)
```

I think I might have something wrong.
Please give me advice.

Thanks.

Comment: The error is due to lack of access to call post on the web service

Comment: Yes, it is. However I have no idea what is lacked. It runs on same server (localhost).

Comment: Are you missing any header params? 403 generally occurs due to authentication mismatch

Comment: It coused `** (Plug.CSRFProtection.InvalidCSRFTokenError) invalid CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) token, make sure all requests include a valid '_csrf_token' param or 'x-csrf-token' header` What should I do for it?

Answer (score 0):

Include [csrf_meta_tag](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Tag.html#csrf_meta_tag/0) in the layout like

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
        ...
```

add header to post

```
function register(state, action) {
    console.log(state.member) // {last_name: 'aaa', first_name: 'bbb', email: 'ccc'}
    axios.post('/members', state.member, {
      headers: {"x-csrf-token": $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")}
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            // handle success
            console.log(response.data);
            let data = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
            // self.setState({hasError: true });
        })
        .finally(function () {
            // always executed
        });

}
```